# Question about Caratheodory extension theorem applied to $[0,1]$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $\mathcal{J}$ be the collection of intervals from $[0,1]$. By intervals, I include singletons, emptyset, etc. So $\mathcal{J}$ looks like

$$\mathcal{J} = \{ (0, 0.7), 0.5 ,\emptyset, [0,1], \cdots \}$$

I have two different $\sigma$-algebras constructed from $\mathcal{J}$. One is $\sigma(\mathcal{J})$, which is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $[0,1]$ and usually denoted as $\mathcal{B}([0,1])$. Another one is the $\sigma$-algebra you get when you apply the Caratheodory extension theorem to $\mathcal{J}$. Let's call it $\mathcal{M}$.

Apparently we have $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{M}$, by definition. However the following comments on my book confuse me and I don't know why they are true.

> It can be shown that $\mathcal{M}$ is in fact much bigger than $\mathcal{B}$; it even has larger cardinality (why?). Furthermore, it turns out that the Lebesgue measure restricted to $\mathcal{B}$ is not complete (why?), though on $\mathcal{M}$ it is.

Why those two statements are true? No proof is provided in the book but I am just curious. For the first statement I simply have no idea how to prove it. For the second statement, by definition we must find some $A \in \mathcal{B}$ with $\mathbb{P}(A) = 0$ and some $B \subset A$ such that $B \notin \mathcal{B}$, but cannot think of an example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to both questions: there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ Borel subsets of $[0, 1]$. On the other hand, the Cantor set has measure zero, so every subset of it is in $\mathcal{M}$. There are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ such subsets, so some must not be Borel, although the Cantor set is Borel.

Comment: Although I don't quite understand what $N_0$ is, but I guess you are saying that the number of subsets of Cantor set is actually larger than number of Borel subsets. That's why there has to be subset of Cantor set that is not Borel? I wonder what those subsets look like?

Comment: @3x89g2 Yeah, that is the point. I have no idea how these sets look like, they're just not Borel. The most accurate description I can give on one of them is by reading the proof of the Cantor theorem, i.e. fix a bijection $f : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{Bor}([0, 1])$ and let $A \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ be defined by $(\forall x \in \mathcal{C}) \big( x \in A \iff x \notin f(x) \big)$ so that for each point $x \in \mathcal{C}$ the set $A$ doesn't agree with some Borel set on $x$.